# Using Same Slug With Multiple Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, duplicates

My Permalinks are the std %postname%. I have several custom post types, eg. 'docs'.

```
function docs_init() {
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
'docs_tax',
'docs',
array(
    'label' => __( 'Documentation_Tax' ),
    'sort' => true,
    'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'docs' )
)
);
}
```

I would like to be able to have duplicate slugs. Eg. I'd like to have a general Page with the slug 'MyPage' and then a Docs post type also with the slug 'MyPage'. The goal is to have users be able to do this:

URL: mysite.com/mypage ---- general Page

URL: mysite.com/docs/mypage ---- posttype Docs

...and this does not work. If the user types /docs/mypage, the browser redirects to /mypage ...even though in the post editor it shows that /docs/mypage is the URL.

I thought that since 'with_front' defaults to true, WordPress would distinguish between the two slugs by assigning the 'front' (ie. the post type.)

How can I get what I want... or is it simply mandatory to have unique slugs?

TIA,

---JC

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you can't as far as the default wordpress installation goes. It's a must to have unique slugs.

You can however mess with the Rewrite API with some custom code to hack your way around this & there aren't any plugins(AFAIK) to help you on your way. So it's definitely a lot easier to just force your users to unique slugs

Comment: Curses. OK, what I don't get is that WP -seems- to -want- to be able to do what I ask. Eg. if I have a custom post 'docs' of slug test, the URL is /docs/test. Fine.  But if I then create a Page with the slug 'test', if you type in /docs/test it ignores the 'docs' and redirects to just /test... so it 'knows' to prepend the posttype, but then chooses to ignore it.

Comment: wordpress always try to match the url to inbuilt mechanisms first & then, if it doesn't find a match, it tries the custom things. The code that creates the url works completely seperate from the one that reads the url. I know it's not a good way & confuses a lot of people but that's how wordpress works. There have been tickets in wordpress trac to address this issue but unfortunately, not implemented

Comment: Can you suggest where in the rewrite engine to look for the code that -reads- the URL. Most of the plug-ins and posts I have researched are concerned re-writing incoming URLs for SEO... ie. the exact opposite of what I want to do. Just need a starting place to search. The WP docs on the rewrite API are pretty thin.

Comment: "wp-includes/rewrite.php", class `WP_Rewrite`, function `rewrite_rules`. This function is in charge of converting a permalink url to the normal url

Comment: I had this problem and I had to wind up doing two taxonomies, but this was due to template hierarchy.